# How to validate NSPredicate before calling fetch

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I create a search `NSPredicate` using a custom format string.  Sometimes the syntax of this string is wrong and when I execute a fetch using a `NSFetchRequest` with this predicate I get a `NSInvalidArgumentException`, for example when the key-path is incorrect.  I would much rather prefer to validate this predicate (call some method that returns `YES` if format is ok), than have an exception thrown that crashes my app.  What can I do?

To rephrase the inquiry into a simple question:

Can I validate the predicate without potentially crashing the app?

Here is example code in Swift:

```
let text = "price > 0.1" // ok, no syntax error
let text = "price > 'abc'" // error
let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: text, argumentArray: [])
let request = NSFetchRequest<Fruit>.init(entityName: "Fruit")    
request.predicate = predicate
request.fetchLimit = 1
let fruit = try myContext.fetch(request) as [Fruit]  // exception thrown here that crashes app
// sometimes the exception can be caught with an obj-c try/catch
// sometimes it can't be caught, and causes program to terminate
// CAN WE HAVE A SOLUTION THAT NEVER CAUSES A CRASH ?
```

Comment: I am not aware of any way to validate predicates, but you can minimise the risk of crashes by using the %K placeholder and #keyPath() directive in  NSPredicate(format:), rather than hard-coding the keypaths.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to validate that a predicate format string is a valid predicate. With format strings, you really need to validate the predicates by (a) testing them during development and (b) verifying that substitution values in predicates are at least the right data type.

If that's a problem, you might find it better to build your predicates in other ways, instead of with format strings. For example, use `NSComparisonPredicate` and `NSCompoundPredicate` to build the predicates from instances of `NSExpression`. The code will be much more verbose, but it will be easier to ensure that your predicate is valid by checking each part of it as you construct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `evaluate(with:)` to validate `NSPredicate`'s format,

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the specified object matches the conditions specified by the predicate.

**Swift 4.2:**

For example,

```
let dataArray = [
        "Amazon",
        "Flipkart",
        "Snapdeal",
        "eBay",
        "Jabong",
        "Myntra",
        "Bestbuy",
        "Alibaba",
        "Shopclue"
    ]
let searchString = "buy"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@", searchString)
let searchResult = dataArray.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
print(searchDataSource)

if !searchResult.isEmpty {
    //success
} else {
    //evaluation failed
}
```

To avoid an exception, you may want to use `try-catch` block

Comment: If the predicate is valid but there is no match it returns false.  Also, if predicate has syntax error you get a crash, ex "SE LF contains %@" ... the idea is to check whether the syntax is correct, without getting a crash.

Comment: I doubt we can validate the string format inside `NSPredicate`, and to avoid crash you can use `try-catch` block

Comment: try-catch doesn't catch an exception, it catches an error

Comment: using an obj-c try/catch works SOMETIMES only .. ie some exceptions are handled, others cause a crash

Comment: agreed, I guess the best we can do is - use the predicate evaluation in the `try block `and handle the exception.