# Understanding error handling with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, error-handling

I have a scenario where I expect something to happen, but it does not and I can't seem to figure out why. I am still new with throwing functions, so I am a bit curious here. Maybe someone can explain why this happen.

I have made this function:

```
func checkExistanceOfMovieAddition(id: Int) -> Result<SavedMovieAddition, CoreDataErrors> {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: SavedMovieAddition.entityName)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "movieID == \(id)")

    do {
        let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
        if let result = fetch.first as? SavedMovieAddition {
            return.success(result)
        } else {
            return.failure(.additionNotFound)
        }
    } catch {
        return.failure(.fetchFailed)
    }
}
```

And it works like a charm. If I search for an id that does not exist I get an empty array and return my custom error type. However.. if I change the line:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "movieID == \(id)")
```

and misspell "movieID" with "movieIDs" which does not exists in my CoreData model the app crashes with:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "keypath movieIDs not found in entity <NSSQLEntity SavedMovieAddition id=2>"
```

Here I would expect it to go the the catch block and return .fetchFailed?

Why is this not happening? But instead the app is crashing? - I thought the whole point of have a do-try-catch block was to eliminate these crashes?

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974473/1187415.

Comment: Ahh.. I see! Thank you. So it's not supposed to jump into the catch block. (Or at least it's not build in) - How can I make it fail so it does? Just to check if it actually works then? I mean, what does that do-try-catch block evaluate then?

Comment: Good question. The documentation says “If there is a problem executing the fetch” – I don't know right now how to trigger that.

Comment: Note also that do/catch in Swift catches *errors.* An invalid predicate throws an Objective-C *exception* and those cannot be caught in Swift.

Comment: Arha, I see! Objective-C exceptions, something new to read about. Thanks again for elaborating, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've had some comments with good explanations. One more thing that may be useful is that you can help to avoid the kind of error you describe by not using bare strings if you can avoid them. When possible, do something that will let the compiler check whether you've misspelled something. In this case, Swift keypaths would help.

You have

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "movieID == \(id)")
```

...which works but is a problem if you misspell the property. If you write this as

```
request.predicate = `NSPredicate(format: "\(#keyPath(SavedMovieAddition.movieID)) == \(id)")`
```

...the key path would be checked by the compiler. If you typed it as `movieIDs`, your code wouldn't compile and you'd get an error saying that `Type 'SavedMovieAddition' has no member 'movieIDs'`. You could also write it this way, if it makes more sense to you:

```
request.predicate = `NSPredicate(format: "%K == \(id)", #keyPath(SavedMovieAddition.movieID))`
```

Comment: Really like your last line. Works perfectly! Thank you! - It does not answer why I don't reach the Catch block (Martin R's answer is closer) but I will mark this as an accepted answer since it prevents this crash from occurring before compilation.